# How to apply Polynomial Transformation to subset of features in scikitlearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Scikitlearn's [PolynomialFeatures](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) facilitates polynomial feature generation.

Here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

# Example data:
X = np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2)


# Works fine
poly = PolynomialFeatures(2)
pd.DataFrame(poly.fit_transform(X))

   0  1  2   3   4   5
0  1  0  1   0   0   1
1  1  2  3   4   6   9
2  1  4  5  16  20  25
```

Question: Is there any capability to only have the polynomial transformation apply to a specified list of features?

e.g.

```
# Use previous dataframe
X2 = X.copy()

# Categorical feature will be handled 
# by a one hot encoder in another feature generation step
X2['animal'] = ['dog', 'dog', 'cat']

# Don't try to poly transform the animal column
poly2 = PolynomialFeatures(2, cols=[1,2]) # <-- ("cols" not an actual param)

# desired outcome:
pd.DataFrame(poly2.fit_transform(X))
   0  1  2   3   4   5   'animal'
0  1  0  1   0   0   1   'dog'
1  1  2  3   4   6   9   'dog'
2  1  4  5  16  20  25   'cat'
```

This would be particularly useful when using the [Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) feature to combine a long series of feature generation and model training code.

One option would be to roll-your-own transformer ([great example](http://michelleful.github.io/code-blog/2015/06/20/pipelines/) by Michelle Fullwood), but I figured someone else would have stumbled across this use case before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In response to the answer from Peng Jun Huang - the approach is terrific but implementation has issues.
(This should be a comment but it's a bit long for that.  Also, don't have enough cookies for that.)

I tried to use the code and had some problems.  After fooling around a bit, I found the following answer to the original question.
The main issue is that the ColumnExtractor needs to inherit from BaseEstimator and TransformerMixin to turn it into an estimator that can be used with other sklearn tools.

My example data shows two numerical variables and one categorical variable.
I used pd.get_dummies to do the one-hot encoding to keep the pipeline a bit
simpler.  Also, I left out the last stage of the pipeline (the estimator) because we have no `y` data to fit; the main point is to show select, process separately and join.

Enjoy.

M.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

X = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'n1': [1, 2, 3], 'n2':[5, 7, 9] })

   cat  n1  n2
0   a   1   5
1   b   2   7
2   c   3   9

# original version had class ColumnExtractor(object)
# estimators need to inherit from these classes to play nicely with others
class ColumnExtractor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns=None):
        self.columns = columns
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        X_cols = X[self.columns]
        return X_cols

# Using pandas get dummies to make pipeline a bit simpler by
# avoiding one-hot and label encoder.     
# Build the pipeline from a FeatureUnion that processes 
# numerical and one-hot encoded separately.
# FeatureUnion puts them back together when it's done.
pipe2nvars = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([('num', 
                                Pipeline([('extract', 
                                           ColumnExtractor(columns=['n1', 'n2'])),
                                          ('poly', 
                                           PolynomialFeatures())  ])),
                               ('cat_var', 
                                ColumnExtractor(columns=['cat_b','cat_c']))])
    )])    

# now show it working...
for p in range(1, 4):
    pipe2nvars.set_params(features__num__poly__degree=p)
    res = pipe2nvars.fit_transform(pd.get_dummies(X, drop_first=True))
    print('polynomial degree: {}; shape: {}'.format(p, res.shape))
    print(res)

polynomial degree: 1; shape: (3, 5)
[[1. 1. 5. 0. 0.]
 [1. 2. 7. 1. 0.]
 [1. 3. 9. 0. 1.]]
polynomial degree: 2; shape: (3, 8)
[[ 1.  1.  5.  1.  5. 25.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  2.  7.  4. 14. 49.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  3.  9.  9. 27. 81.  0.  1.]]
polynomial degree: 3; shape: (3, 12)
[[  1.   1.   5.   1.   5.  25.   1.   5.  25. 125.   0.   0.]
 [  1.   2.   7.   4.  14.  49.   8.  28.  98. 343.   1.   0.]
 [  1.   3.   9.   9.  27.  81.  27.  81. 243. 729.   0.   1.]]
```

Comment: Really appreciate this, leonkato!

Answer (score 8):

[PolynomialFeatures](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html), like many other transformers in sklearn, does not have a parameter that specifies which column(s) of the data to apply, so it is not straightforward to put it in a Pipeline and expect to work.

A more general way to do this, you can use [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) and specify transformer(s) for each feature you have in your dataframe using another pipeline.

A simple example could be:

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures, OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


X = pd.DataFrame({'cat_var': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'num_var': [1, 2, 3]})


class ColumnExtractor(object):
    def __init__(self, columns=None):
        self.columns = columns

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        X_cols = X[self.columns]

    return X_cols


pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
        ('num_var', Pipeline([
            ('extract', ColumnExtractor(columns=['num_var'])),
            ('poly', PolynomialFeatures(degree=2))
        ])),
        ('cat_var', Pipeline([
            ('extract', ColumnExtractor(columns=['cat_var'])),
            ('le', LabelEncoder()),
            ('ohe', OneHotEncoder()),
        ]))
    ])),
    ('estimator', LogisticRegression())
])
```

Comment: This is great. I'm accepting this answer because it does not rely on an additional library.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is, check out [sklearn-pandas](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/sklearn-pandas)

This should work (there should be a more elegant solution, but can't test it now):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper

X2.columns = ['col0', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'animal']

mapper = DataFrameMapper([
('col0', PolynomialFeatures(2)),
('col1', PolynomialFeatures(2)),
('col2', PolynomialFeatures(2)),
('col3', PolynomialFeatures(2)),
('col4', PolynomialFeatures(2)),
('col5', PolynomialFeatures(2)),
('Animal', None)])

X3 = mapper.fit_transform(X2)
```

Comment: Where can I specify the model that should be used in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Improvement to @plumbus_bouquet code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper

X2.columns = ['col0', 'col1', 'col2', 'animal']
degree = 2

mapper = DataFrameMapper(
(['col0', 'col1', 'col2'], PolynomialFeatures(degree))
)

X3 = mapper.fit_transform(X2)
```

Another way (I prefer that) is **to use [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html) from sklearn.compose**. I find it easy to use in the pipeline.

For selecting columns, you've multiple ways. Some of the Ways are:

1. Based on column names
2. Based on Data Types (include & exclude option)
3. Index position
4. Slicing
5. RegEx

See [example here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/justmarkham/scikit-learn-tips/blob/master/notebooks/02_select_columns.ipynb).